# pre-update svn script to filter what get

Tags: svn, hook

Imagine a repository with many kind of files.
Then, I want to get from this repository just some kind of files in a "filter process".

I mean ALL FILES are versioned. But to my local work, I just wanna i.e get *.php files, ignoring download *.jpg instead.

I think about client-site hook script (pre-update).
Anyone know if is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to export specific files from your working copy? Or trying to create a working copy with only certain file types?

Comment: I'm trying to create a working copy with only certain file types.

We have repositories with 300MB including PHP, PSD, JPG, ... A progamer just need to download from repository to his working place PHP, JS and HTML files... But a designer needs to download PSD instead.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to checkout a partial repository. I suggest you reorganize your repo to separate your sources from publishable assets.

Comment: Wrong.  See "sparse checkout."

Comment: Sorry Michael a shallow checkout won't do what DrLuk is asking. It only works on directory depths and not on extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout individual directories from svn. If you put all your images in a directory `svn/trunk/images` and all source code in `svn/trunk/php` people can checkout the trees separately.

Maybe you could add soft-links to link to these files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done easily using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/).

You can create a working copy with `depth = empty` first.  Then, using the repo browser, open the directory that contains the files you want.  You can multi-select the desired files (if they are all files of the same type, you can sort by extension first to make it easier), then right-click and select "Update item to revision".

This will pull down only the selected files into your working copy, and nothing else.

Comment: This assumes a user is running TortoiseSVN or some tool with a UI to browse the repository. On a large repo a user will be forced to navigate to directory, select and update multiple times. Not good.